# Unit testing a service that uses $resource

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to wrap a unit test around an existing service and at am a loss to explain the data that is showing up in the test results and causing my test to fail. First, the players:

Service Method:

```
function createAddressType(newAddressType) {
var defObj = $q.defer();
addressTypesResource = $resource(addressTypesAPI, {}, {query: { method: 'GET'}, create: { method: 'POST'}, update: { method: 'PUT'}, remove: { method: 'DELETE'}});

var newType = addressTypesResource.create({'addresstypes': [
        {'addresstype': newAddressType}
]});
newType.$promise.then(function(data){
    defObj.resolve(data);
});

return defObj.promise;
}
```

Unit Test:

```
it('should try to create the passed address type on the server', function(){
    var newType = addressTypeService.blankModel('123', '456');
    newType.type_name._value_ = 'Fred';
    httpBackend.expect('POST','/v1/rest/addresstype', {addresstypes:[{addresstype:newType}]})
    .respond({addresstypes:[{addresstype:{
    'type_name': {'_value_': 'Fred'},
    'origin_application': {'_value_': '123'},
    'subsidiary_sid': {'_value_': '456'},
    'sid':{'_value_':'1234567890'}
}}]});
    var returnValue = {};
    var createType = addressTypeService.create(newType);
    createType.then(function(data){
        returnValue = data;
    });
    httpBackend.flush();

    expect(returnValue).toEqual({addresstypes:[{addresstype:{
        'type_name': {'_value_': 'Fred'},
    'origin_application': {'_value_': '123'},
    'subsidiary_sid': {'_value_': '456'},
    'sid':{'_value_':'1234567890'}
}}]});
});
```

The test result:

```
Expected { addresstypes : [ { addresstype : { type_name : { _value_ : 'Fred' }, origin_application : { _value_ : '123' }, subsidiary_sid : { _value_ : '456' }, sid : { _value_ : '1234567890' } } } ], $promise : { then : Function, catch : Function, finally : Function }, $resolved : true } 
to equal { addresstypes : [ { addresstype : { type_name : { _value_ : 'Fred' }, origin_application : { _value_ : '123' }, subsidiary_sid : { _value_ : '456' }, sid : { _value_ : '1234567890' } } } ] }.
```

Can anybody tell me why the `$promise...` portion is still hanging on? I originally had this service not using `$q` and just returning the `$resource` call, but then we started resolving things internally before passing them back (we'll eventually have to add code before and after the main promise) and when in production this runs fine, but the unit test is giving me grey hairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promise being included in the response is expected. So you need to check for returnvalue.addresstypes.

```
expect(returnValue.addresstypes.toString()).toEqual({addresstypes:[{addresstype:{
            'type_name': {'_value_': 'Fred'},
            'origin_application': {'_value_': '123'},
            'subsidiary_sid': {'_value_': '456'},
            'sid':{'_value_':'1234567890'}
        }}]}.toString());
```